# Template specialization for constructor based on type

Tags: c++

I've been looking for this for quite a while, and I maybe I just don't know what words to use to find it.

I have a template class that accepts a type, and would like the constructor to be different depending on if that type is a pointer or not. Here is some code to explain what I mean.

```cpp
template <class T> class Example
{
    bool choice;
public:
    //Only if T is not a pointer type
    Example() : choice{false}
    {}

    //Only if T is a pointer type
    Example(bool choice) : choice{choice}
    {}
}
```

I have experimented with `std::enable_if` and `std::is_pointer<T>` but with no luck.

Comment: You can make a template specialization for pointers: `template <class T> class Example { }; template <class T> class Example<T*> { };`. (That wouldn't cover the constructors only.) FYI: [Partial template specialization for pointers](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/partial-template-specialization-for-pointers/)

Comment: "_but with no luck_": What exactly didn't work out for you? SFINAE with `std::enable_if` is the correct approach (before C++20) if partial specialization isn't preferable.

Comment: The question is valid, but needing this in the first place might be a design smell. I'm curious why you want to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either specialize the whole class:

```
template <class T> struct Example {
    bool choice;
    Example() : choice{false} {}
};

template <class T> struct Example<T*> {
    bool choice;
    Example(bool choice) : choice{choice} {}
};

int main() {

    Example<int> e;
    Example<int*> f(false);
}
```

Or via `std::enable_if`:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <class T> struct Example {
    bool choice;

    template <typename U = T, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_pointer_v<U>,bool> = true>
    Example() : choice{false} {}

    template <typename U = T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_pointer_v<U>,bool> = true>
    Example(bool choice) : choice{choice} {}
};

int main() {
    Example<int> e;
    Example<int*> f(false);
}
```

Only one of the conditions for `std::enable_if` is `true`. Either `std::is_pointer_v<T>` is `true` then the first constructor is a substitution failure or it is `false` then the second is discarded.

Comment: I didn't realize there was an "old" way and a "new" way. This is extremely helpful. Everything I've read made enable_if muddled and confusing rather than just a clean example. Also just a note for those reading this answer and not using c++17. `std::is_pointer_v<T>` is equivalent to `std::is_pointer<T>::value`.

Comment: @Questionable if you refer to inital wording of the answer then please reload ;). The first was possible already with ancient standards. The second as well, just with more handwritten almost unreadable code. C++11 made things simpler by introducing `enable_if`. The "new" way is concepts in C++20, but unfortunately I am not fluent enough to present that

Comment: I realize this is beyond the scope of the original question, but is it true that unlike constructors, destructors can not be controlled this way?

Comment: no you cant make the destructor a member template, but you can call a different function template in the destructor. However, consider the comment under your question about design. If `Example` for pointers is doing something so different from `Example` for non-pointers, why do you want to pretend that they are the same `Example` ?

Comment: Good to know on the destructors. As for the design of the 32 member functions I have in my class, only the constructor needs modification and the destructor needs slight modification.